# On back key pressed everything gets minimized

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult, onbackpressed

Am new to programming.. App was working well.. But i run into some out of memmory error, fixed it using leak canary now whenever back button is pressed fragment holding activity gets killed and app gets minimized, even on activity result is not running, crop activity, qr scan, location activity nothing is working,Parent activity is getting stopped and destroyed rather than stoped and saved, if i change this activity  to be main activity in the manifest then there is no problem .. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Override the onbackpressed method to minimize the app. Not terminate.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{

this.moveTaskToBack(true);

}
```

Comment: Still not working.. When i navigate away from the activity or run an on activity result to crop image, its getting destroyed

Comment: Where did you put it. Inside the current activity ?

Comment: The activity works when i set the activity to be main activity, launching activity using intent filter in the manifest

Comment: <activity android:launchMode =“singleTop”/> put in for the activity in manifest.xml